# Does the Ocarina have a use asides from playing music?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Does the Ocarina have a functional use asides from playing a random tune whenever you whip it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Gamerevolution](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/640134-animal-crossing-new-horizons-ocarina-purpose-zelda-easter-egg) it is just a Legend of Zelda Easter egg that plays a random tune.

> Created using clay, a fairly valuable resource, the Animal Crossing:
>   New Horizons ocarina requires quite an investment to craft. After
>   putting in all that clay, surely the ocarina has some secret function
>   and benefit? **Well, it plays music…**
>
> Yep, at least at the time of writing, **the only purpose of the ocarina
>   is to play a tune. The ocarina plays random notes, with the player
>   unfortunately not able to influence which sounds are used. It’s just a
>   random song.**

And corroborated on [the animal crossing wiki](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Ocarina)

> It is made from clay, and **plays random notes when interacted with**. The
>   relevant button can be held down to hold a note.

Comment: If only it could control time or the weather...